# Netbeans ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, netbeans

I saw various posts on this topic but they didnt help me. I deleted my Netbeans cache and Compile on Save was not checked. I just try to load a .dat File and use the data that was serialized in there. It works perfectly in JavaEditor but I get the error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Example` in Netbeans.

The code I used to load the .dat :

```
  public static void load(){
    ArrayList<Example> ex = new ArrayList<Example>();

    FileInputStream fis;
    ObjectInputStream ois;
    try{
      fis = new FileInputStream("ExampleList.dat");
      ois = new ObjectInputStream (fis);
      while (fis.available()>0){
        Example exam = (Example)ois.readObject();
        ex.add(exam);
      }
      ois.close();
      fis.close();

    } catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
```

The Example.jar:

```
package ExampleTest;
import java.io.*;
public class Example implements Serializable{
 private String name;

public Example(){
}

//Getter and Setter

}
```

Doing something in the main method like `Example ex = new Example();` works perfectly fine so netbeans should have found the class..

Comment: show full stacktrace and full code with imports and everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a `class version compatibility` issue, and that happens because you make change on your class after serialized object that you are trying to deserialized,so the new generated `serialVersionUID` is not equal to previous one,

so you have to declare `static long serialVersionUID`, by doing that you can safely make changes on your class.

also check that stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/285809/8053533)

hope that helps.

Comment: the only change I made is to add it to a package.. I didn't even add something like an attribute. Is it possible to just change this and continue using this .dat as before or do i actually have to create a new one?

Comment: check that java doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#6678

Comment: section 5.6.1 Incompatible Changes: point 2 :"Moving classes up or down the hierarchy - This cannot be allowed since the data in the stream appears in the wrong sequence."